why when Using wrapper query with base 64 I get low performance?
I noticed that when I run the same query from Kibana with a wrapper query in base 64, I get low performance.
Can someone explain why? is it a known issue?
one more important thing: size of data: more than 20GB.
running the query from Kibbana without wrapper query took 10sec,
with the wrapper query I got timeout exception.
and from Java client using the wrapperQuery it took one minute.
this is the original query not in base 64:
GET /baseelements/_count {   "query" : {
     "bool":
    {
      "filter":
      [
        {
          "term": {
            "session": {
              "value": "661c1db36aad7e28f82da16f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "stream": {
              "value": "abc",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not":
      [
          { "terms" : {"source": ["inform","MISC"] }},
          { "wildcard" : {"name" :{"value": "*INFRA: Timer*"}}},
          { "terms" : {"name" : ["who", "Timer" ]}},
          { "wildcard" : {"name" :{"value": "*INF information commit id*"}}},
          { "wildcard" : {"name" :{"value": "*Serial Number*"}}},
          { "wildcard" : {"name" :{"value": "*Inf: Code Coverag*"}}}
      ]
    }   } }


When you say "from Kibana", do you mean sending the wrapper query in Dev Tools or from some other app?

from Kibana tool server, also when I send it from Java client.

Can you show how you're sending it from Kibana dev tools?
